# Preferred way to add a third party library to a git project

Tags: c++, git, github

Say I am using gtest and I usually included the sources in my project (and cmake) so that they were built locally - as recommended.

What is the preferred way to add this to a (public) git repositry (e.g., on GitHub). Add the thrid party code as well (in a subfolder)? I'm used to working on private svn repositories where we just followed this approach. Not sure if it is recommended for public projects. On top of that, frameworks will include their licences but I'm not sure if I have to explicitly reference them in the project root as well.

Is it possible to reference the code for the framework somehow, i.e. do not commit the code but make checkouts or project builds donwload framework code as needed? Is it better pratice to simply state that there is a dependency and let everyone handle it locally?

Comment: Since you mentioned CMake, you might want to take a look at [`ExternalProject_Add()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/ExternalProject.html).

Comment: I will, thanks. Looks great for my current use-case. I guess the question is still relevant, though, since I think I might face the same problem again in a project that doesn't use cmake.

Comment: In retrospect, ExternalProject worked great but the required connection for building turned out to be very problematic for my use-cases (e.g. working on the train) and git submodules turned out to be the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use git submodules to reference dependencies.

Git submodules allows you to include a completely different repository on a given directory and keep only the reference.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules